# curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length

Tags: centos7

I cannot fine the solutions for my issue to curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

i have tried everything and how to fix this
server: apache centos 7

Comment: have your a redirection to HTTPS on port 80 ?

Comment: not sure
i have copied the working ssl.conf and httpd.conf file to this issue conf file

Comment: You can try to force using the default HTTPS port in your request : `https://example.com:443/` and check if you still have the error

Comment: how to do thatcan you provide the command line

Comment: replace the url in your actual command line or in browser if the website is accessible via it. Just happend `:443` after the FQDN

Comment: where to add that command

Comment: Take your curl command and just append the port after the FQDN

Comment: curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length

Comment: can you edit your post and write the command line you use

Comment: curl https://taxi-webdesign.com:443

Answer (score 2):

The website you configured have no SSL certificate, then it can't deliver a HTTPS connexion and do HTTP over HTTPS, which produce and error.

You have to configure your website with SSL certificates by [following the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html)